# unwanted qualifiers appearing in some of the rows when exporting to tab limited file SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on some SSRS reports which already were built using Crystal reports.

When I use the same SQL script in SSRS and export to tab limited text file, for some of the rows there is a symbol (") at the beginning and end of the row, but this is not coming for the all of the rows, only for some of the rows in the result set. Also my script returns single column and which is concatenated filed.

I checked the settings in my rsreportserver.config and its like

```
<Qualifier></Qualifier> for the tablimitted format.
```

I am bit confused in this case and I really appreciate if anybody can help me in this.

Thanks,
Sivajith

Comment: I would assume that the qualifier is there because there is an actual tab in your data and there qualifier is there so it doesn't get interpreted as a column.

Comment: So I have to look at the specific row and needs to figure out this. Right?

Comment: Let's start by seeing what you want for results.

Comment: the thing is that its only appearing only for some of the rows not for all the rows. that confuses me

Comment: Check the data to see if there is a tab character, CHAR(9), on the rows with the qualifiers.

Comment: its not there..

Comment: Now I'm confused too. Not what I expected.